# Python : Fraction(*map(int, input().split()))

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi I want to know how *map works here:

```
Fraction(*map(int, input().split()))
```

I understood that it returns the parameters to the outer function -  (Fraction) here.

But I also tried some thing like this -

```
List(*map(int, input().split()))
```

and

```
sum(*map(int, input().split()))
```

Its not working.

So I am not sure what actually *map returns. Need help on this! Thanks!

Comment: `*` spreads the result of `map()` into separate arguments to the function. But `list` and `sum` don't expect multiple arguments. They expect a single argument containing the sequence to iterate over.

Comment: When you say "Its not working." you always should tell us *exactly what isn't working*

Comment: map returns a map object. You need to convert it to list so that you can pass it to sum.
`sum(list(map(int,input().split())))`